Jest issues with properties not exist on type 'Assertion' (Typescript, nextJS)
I have an issues where all of my "toBeInTheDocument", "toEqual" and "toBe" assertions have errors, like: "Property 'toBeInTheDocument' does not exist on type 'Assertion'.ts(2339)"
I tried all of the tips and solutions:

importing @testing-library/jest-dom on the top of the test file
importing the same in the jest.setup.ts file
importing @testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect in the jest.setup.ts file
My jest.config.ts is in the root dir along with the jest.setup.ts and has this line: setupFilesAfterEnv: ["/jest.setup.ts"]

I also tried to add the @testing-library/jest-dom to my tsconfig.json's types, but it always says: "Cannot find type definition file for '@testing-library/jest-dom'.
The file is in the program because: Entry point of type library '@testing-library/jest-dom' specified in compilerOptions" "
Tried to add "./node_modules/@testing-library" to my typeRoots, but it didn't help.
The only thing that fixed it was using the "jest-without-globals" package, but unfortunately that would lock the jest@23-25 versions, so that would not be too ideal.
Using Next, Typescript, React, Jest, Cypress that could be relevant.
Versions:
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^10.4.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^16.1.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.14",
    "cypress": "^13.16.1"

My jest.config.ts:
    import type { Config } from "jest";
    import nextJest from "next/jest";
    
    const createJestConfig = nextJest({
      dir: "./",
    });
    
    const config: Config = {
      clearMocks: true,
      globals: {
        fetch: global.fetch,
        Request: global.Request,
        Response: global.Response,
      },
    
      collectCoverage: true,
    
      coverageDirectory: "coverage",
    
      coverageProvider: "v8",
    
      testEnvironment: "jsdom",
    
      moduleNameMapper: {
        "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
      },
    
      setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts"],
    };
    
    export default createJestConfig(config);

My tsconfig.json:
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2017",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./node_modules/@testing-library"],
        "types": ["cypress", "node", "jest" /*"@testing-library/jest-dom"*/],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "bundler",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "incremental": true,
        "baseUrl": "src/",
        "plugins": [
          {
            "name": "next"
          }
        ],
        "paths": {
          "@/*": ["./src/*"]
        }
      },
      "include": [
        "next-env.d.ts",
        "**/*.ts",
        "**/*.tsx",
        ".next/types/**/*.ts",
        "**/*.spec.ts",
        "**/*.d.ts"
      ],
      "exclude": ["node_modules"]
    }

jest.setup.ts only has these 2 lines:
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
Can someone see what could be the issue? I tried I think everything that I could find online, but probably I'm just not noticing something. Or does someone knows an alternative for jest-without-globals that is a maintained package?
Thank you!

This will help you https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#type-definitions.

Thanks, it helped, just needed to import another package too :)

Glad it helped.

SOLUTION for me
Thanks to Rakesh's comment, I installed @jest/globals and imported expect from that. I also set esModuleInterop to false in my tsconfig and installed this package: @types/testing-library__jest-dom
Now my code is without red squiggly lines :)
